# App Gradle, how I can fix error while use Firebase core?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Here's the build.gradle-app file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    compile 'com.felipecsl:gifimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this the build-gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha05'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I want to create a firebase auth, and on the settings page says to use firebase-core-16.0.1. I have followed the instructions recommended when an error appears, by adding firebase-analytics.

please help me to correct the error code on the gradle, or can i know the use of the google service or dependency version that I can use.

Comment: use same version for all `Firebase` dependencies

Comment: still not working, even I only use firebase-core 16.0.4.
appeared recomendation to add firebase analytics and I still error

Comment: remove `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.1.1'` and `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4'` and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha05'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

And please also remove the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.1.1'
```

Comment: Hi Steven! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: I have tried it but it's still an error. Does the Android Studio version affect library usage in Gradle?

Comment: Still an error, which is? Yes, should be compatibile.

Comment: in this line,  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'. i will try to update android studio first

Comment: Ok and keep me posted.

Comment: Hi Alex Mamo, thank's for your answer. II have updated Android Studio to the latest version,  and it fixed my previous problem.

Thank' u very much